# Filter datadog metric tags based on range

Tags: python, datadog, datadog-dashboard

In my python app I am publishing a metric with some tags for example:

```py
datadog.statsd.gauge(
    metric="generation_completed",
    value=float((timezone.now() - search_report_task.created).total_seconds()),
    tags=[
        "format: single",
        f"count:{count}",
    ],
)
```

Now I want to create a graph set metric as `generation_completed`  , but I want only those metric where the `tag` count  is `between` a `particular range` `for example. 0 to 5000`

The issue I am `not able` to `set condition on tag` so that any other metric that does not fall in that tag range should not show up in the graph.

Is there anyway to do it with current gauge or I have to use something else?

Comment: If you know which ranges you are interested in ahead of time, my suggestion is to put the logic for identifying those ranges into the code and then applying tags based on the ranges, rather than putting the count in the tags. For example, `if count < 5000`, add the tag `under5k`, and so on.

Comment: @bwest , i do know range and yeah i thought about this, but this not generic and if i ever want to change range i would have to change the metric names also but yeah if i find nothing else this will be the solution.

Comment: The main problem is that you're trying to store a metric in a tag, and tags aren't meant for that. Try to create two metrics that you can query together afterward.

Comment: i have to explore the two metric, let me check that